# What is the most common flamenco guitar scale?

Tags: flamenco-guitar

I've noticed that strumming from an F to an E chord, or even just the note itself, produces a characteristic flamenco sound, if the root is E.  What are the other notes to this scale?

Comment: You are probably searching the chord progression Am-G-F-E. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flamenco_mode and https://www.guitar-chord.org/articles/flamenco.html

Comment: This sounds like one for the Kid… the [Riviera Kid](https://youtu.be/lRF-vI56cr0)!

Answer (score 16):

That sound you're hearing known as the [Flamenco Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flamenco_mode#:%7E:text=In%20music%20theory%2C%20the%20flamenco,in%20flamenco%20songs%20and%20pieces.), or the Major Phrygian mode.

The traditional **Phrygian mode** is the third mode of the major scale - essentially starting the major scale on the third degree, so E Phrygian would be: E - F - G - A - B - C - D - E

The traditional Phrygian mode is used in Flamenco, too, but to turn this into Major Phrygian (aka the Flamenco mode), just raise the third degree, so: E - F - G♯ - A - B - C - D - E

There is another variation that also raises the seventh degree: E - F - G♯ - A - B - C - D♯ - E

I should note, though, that Flamenco is a whole genre of music that is not just based off one scale. Using this mode, you can make music that sounds kind of Flamenco-like, but it is just one small ingredient in creating real Flamenco music.

Comment: What's awesome is that by simply using the notes without any sharps or flats and choosing your lowest note as the root automatically makes you do phrygian on guitar. One might say flamenco is the most natural thing for guitar.

Comment: When you raise the 3rd of the Phrygian mode that is equivalent to raising the 7th of the relative minor mode in the same key.  Example, E phyg #3 is just A harmonic minor.  The real question is what progression are you playing this over?  E phyg (#3) over E min?  Or over Am?

Answer (score 13):

### The Simple Answer

The F to E transition marks the last two chords in an **Andalusian Cadence** (i - VII - VI - V, in your case Amin - G - F - E), which is a very prominent characteristic in Flamenco music. To think about Flamencos in a simple way, you can think about playing in a **harmonic minor**, which follows the pattern WS - HS - WS - WS - WS - HS - Aug 2nd - HS. You're in the key of A minor, so your harmonic minor would look like:

[image]

The G natural comes from the fact that the Andalusian scale is calculated from the natural minor. Because you are going for a major chord (indicated with V instead of v), the G# would arise as an accidental from your fifth step

### The More Complicated Answer

To that point, there is such a thing called **Flamenco Mode**, which is the Major Phrygian mode.

In the (non-major) Phrygian mode,

[image: Normal Phrygian scale]

you follow the pattern of HS - WS - WS - WS - HS - WH - WH. To contrast, a Major Phrygian mode would have you raise the third (and seventh, as necessary). You would be playing in E **Major** Phrygian:

[image: Major Phrygian scale]

EDIT: As a little side note, you'll notice that if you don't sharp the seventh in your Major Phrygian scale, you'll end up with something that resembles a harmonic minor scale that starts from an E instead of an A. Something is afoot! :)

Comment: I think the “Andalusian Cadence” as ⅰ-Ⅶ-Ⅵ-Ⅴ is actually more common in Rock/Pop than it is in Flamenco! What really is characteristic about flamenco is how the Ⅵ-Ⅴ transition is played with.

Comment: To me E.... F G F E sounds like the most flamenco sequence

Comment: This is a much better answer.  It points out the relation (correct relation) to the progression.  +1

Comment: Indeed, the Amin - G - F - E progression gives such a strong flamenco feels to it, particularly when it resolves from the II to the I, ie, F to E when strummed.  The half-step gives it so much flavour.

Answer (score 6):

You’re certainly looking for the **Andalusian Cadence:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andalusian_cadence

If you’re strumming or picking triad-patterns with the chords of the Phrygian cadence Am-G-F-E and improvise on the notes mi-fa-si-la, you will have the typical Flamenco sound.

https://www.guitar-chord.org/articles/flamenco.html

Answer (score 0):

## Comprehensive Flamenco scale

I highly recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QG-8BHhd59Y) ("The comprehensive flamenco scale explained") from [Adam Del Monte](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_del_Monte):

[image]

He explains how the *comprehensive Flamenco scale* is built, what the notes are, and how they relate to the [Andalusian cadence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andalusian_cadence), to [Phrygian mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrygian_mode) and the [harmonic minor scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_scale).

The notes of the scale in E are : E, F, G, G#, A, B, C, D, D#.

In order to learn them, I recommend playing the E Phrygian first:

[image: E Phrygian]

and then add G# (borrowed from the A harmonic minor scale), and D# as leading tone:

[image: E comprehensive Flamenco scale]